# Oracle : 'Count over Partition by' output on first row of the keyword alone

Tags: sql, oracle11g, distinct, window-functions

I have to query a table which will look like as follows.

```
select count(*) over (PARTITION BY offer_status) as count, name, status
from tablename
```

**Output will be as:**

3  |  name1  |  entered
3  |  name1  |  entered
3  |  name2  |  cleared
1  |  name3  |  completed
3  |  name3  |  cleared
3  |  name1  |  entered
3  |  name2  |  cleared

**I would like to get it as :**

3  |  name1  |  entered
    |  name3  |  entered
3  |  name2  |  cleared
1  |  name3  |  completed
    |  name3  |  cleared
    |  name3  |  entered
    |  name3  |  cleared

To get the count of status only for the first occurance of the keyword (of status), as it is not necessary to get the count again and again.

Or you can suggest me any other way to get it done.

Comment: SQL tables represent unordered sets.  There is no concept of "first row", unless you have another column that specifies the ordering.  And, in case, you are wondering, turning the other values into `NULL` will not affect performance.

Comment: I edited description to "first occurance"

Comment: @smileyface . . . I don't think you understand the concept of "unordered set".  There is not first occurrence in a SQL table, unless defined by some other column, such as an id or insertion time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would do something like:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN rn=1 THEN cnt END cnt, order_name, status
FROM
(
SELECT count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY status) cnt,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY status ORDER BY order_name) rn,
  order_name,status
FROM input_table
)
```

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/40412)

As Gordon Linoff said, you need some sort of ordering. I ordered them by order_name but if you have some other field in the table you could use that instead.